# $L_1,L_2$ linear and $L_1\circ L_2$ nilpotent $\implies L_2\circ L_1$ nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, nilpotence

Given $L_1,L_2\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ and $L_1L_2$ nilpotent. I have to show that $L_2L_1$ ist nilpotent either.
Let $L_1,L_2\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ and $L_1L_2$ nilpotent. Let $v\in V$. Than there $\exists m\in\mathbb{N}: (L_1L_2)^m(v)=0$

Is it true that $(L_1L_2)^m(v)=0 \Leftrightarrow L_1^m(L_2(v))=0$?
If so than  $(L_1L_2)$ nilpotent would imply $L_1$ nilpotent and I can go on by myself. If not... I could use some help.

Thanks, Matthias

Comment: Is $V$ any vector space, or is it finite dimensional?

Comment: @Gae.S.yes, it is finite dimensional.

Comment: turns out it was an unnecessary detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(L_1L_2)^n = 0$, then $(L_2L_1)^{n+1} = L_2(L_1L_2)^nL_1 = 0$

Comment: I understand your proof, but can you please answer my question if is true: $(L_1L_2)^m(v)=0 \Leftrightarrow L_1^m(L_2(v))=0$

Comment: @Matthias No: it is entirely possible that $L_2$ is nilpotent and $L_1=I$.

Comment: @Gae.S. I can't see my mistake. $(L_1^m(L_2(v)) = 0$. Since $L_1$ is linear, it follows that $L_2(v) = 0$. Now there are two possibilities. 1) $v=0$ than $L_2$ is $I$. 2) $v\neq0$ than $L_2(v)$ is nilpotent. I guess my mistake is at 2)

Comment: It doesn't follow that $L_2(v) = 0$

Comment: @ChristopherHughes I don't understand why this is not following. My only explanation would be that $(L_1L_2)^m(v)$ does not imply $L_1^m(L_2(v))$. So why is this not true?

Comment: For example $v = \begin{pmatrix} {1 \\ 1}\end{pmatrix}$ $L_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $L_1 = I$, and $m = 2$

Comment: @Matthias $(L_1L_2)^mv=0$ certainly does not imply $L_1^mL_2v=0$, because the reason I have mentioned. I can't quite decide right now if the other implication works, though I'm leaning towards "no".

Comment: @ChristopherHughes Thanks!

Comment: @Gae.S.Thanks, I'm convinced now :-)